# How to make a UIView or TableView to fit the preferredContentSize of a popover?

Tags: ios, popover

I wanna show a popover with a 100X100 imageView or tableView.
Usually I have to create an imageView on the corner Of the popoverView,like this.
(http://snappyimages.nextwavesrl.netdna-cdn.com/img/c7533f30a6ebef7c017521fd8f84452e.png)

But if I change the the preferredContentSize,I  have to change the the size of imageView too.

Q1:
Is it the right way to create the content of a popover ?

Q2:
Is there a  way to make the imageView or tableView to fit the preferredContentSize automatically?

Comment: Use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) for this.

Comment: @NicolasMiari  I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the anwser!

Impelement code in presentating controller.

`popoverController. preferredContentSize = popoverControoler.yourTableView.contentSize;`

`popoverController. preferredContentSize = popoverControoler.yourImageView.frame.size;`

or
implement the code in popoverController (make sure yourView has been laid out)

`-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.preferredContentSize=yourTableView.contentSize;
}`

`-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.preferredContentSize=yourImageView.contentSize;
}`

Comment: it is better to set preferedContentSize in
`code`
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize
    }
`code`